# Are there any problems with calling a getter in the parameters of a setter?

Tags: java

Is it okay to call the getter inside the parameter of a setter to add?
example:

```
managerList[i].setTotalHours(managerList[i].getTotalHours() + 1);
```

Is there any problems with setting total hours by calling managerList[i].getTotalHours() and adding 1?

Comment: Why do you think there would be? Why do you think there wouldn't? What are you worried about?

Comment: It would probably be better to add a `incrementHours()` method to the class itself. Then you could use `managerList[i].incrementHours();`, perhaps make it take an `int`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Exactly! i was writing the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with that, also it could be more cleaner if you create a method to add one hour to manager total hours:

### Example:

```
public void addOneHour()
{
  this.hours++;
}
```

So then you simply call:

```
managerList[i].addOneHour();
```

---

### Improved solution:

Or a parametrized solution as @Elliott Frisch pointed out (to extend functionallity) could be:

```
incrementHours( int n)
{
   this.hours += n;
}
```

and then:

```
managerList[i].incrementHours(1);
```