# Is there any relevance in calling a getter within a setter for the same property at any instant of execution?

Tags: java

I've seen a code which I felt meaningless

```
class CarFactory {
    public void setFullCar(Car car) {
        // some code
        car.setColor(car.getColor());
        car.setWeight(car.getWeight());
        car.setAcceleration(car.getAcceleration());
        // some code
    }
}
```

Of course, there is nothing wrong with calling a getter within setter [Are there any problems with calling a getter in the parameters of a setter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40457090/are-there-any-problems-with-calling-a-getter-in-the-parameters-of-a-setter). But I'm wondering whether there is any importance to this line at any instant of execution? I mean we are just fetching a property value and setting it to the same property again - just a waste of code.

My other doubt is why the compiler (being pretty good in anticipation) ain't giving any warnings for this sort of code.

Comment: Why the compiler should raise a warning ? Try to assign an existing variable to itself, the compiler won't tell you anything, your IDE may.

Comment: Why do you think the compiler would do so?

Comment: The compiler can't know that `getColor` and `setColor` don't have any other side-effects.

Comment: "I'm wondering whether there is any importance to this line at any instant of execution? I mean we are just fetching a property value and setting it to the same property again - just a waste of code" - it would be interesting to study how the compiler and runtime optimise this, if you're interested in this sort of thing

Comment: are you sure the `getter` is just getting the value, and the `setter` is just setting it? e.g. no logging involved? or some database access? something else? (and are you sure that it really is using the same `car`, not maybe `this.car.setColor(car.getColor())`?

Comment: @Carlos Heuberger, ya just setting and getting - perfect encapsulation

Comment: also no *magic*  like code weaving (aspectj, mockito, coverage, ...)? Have you asked the author why this is being done? Is your last comment valid for all implementation and all subclasses?

Comment: the code is written by a fresher, so there is no point of asking since he's learning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the compiler, the setter and getter are just normal methods, so it does not warn.

Answer (score 0):

It nearly never makes any sense to call a setter with the value of the getter of the SAME object. So I assume there will be a newCar object instead and you want to transport the values over.

```
class CarFactory {
    public void setFullCar(Car car) {
        // some code
        newCar.setColor(car.getColor());
        newCar.setWeight(car.getWeight());
        newCar.setAcceleration(car.getAcceleration());
        // some code
    }
}
```

This assumes a `Car` object with getters that do nothing but just return their value.

```
public int getWeight() {
  return mass;
}
```

But in the FUTURE there will be flying cars (filled with helium for lift) that do this:

```
public int getWeight() {
  return mass - lift;
}
```

If you factory class only used `car.setWeight(car.mass)` it would fail for flying cars.